Construct a banded Matrix efficiently with Matlab and Yalmip
I have th following Matlab-Yalmip code:
P=cell(1+m*2,1)
for i=1:m*2+1     
    P{i}=sdpvar(n);                                                                 
end 

phi=cell(1+m*2,1);  
 
for i=1:m*2+1
  phi{i} = A'*P{i}+P{i}*A;
end

for i=1:m*2
  phi{i} = phi{i}+(i)*P{i+1};
end

I Try to construct the following banded Matrix with Matlab:
Please, Can you help me how efficently construct $$\Phi$$

